# Add Line Break With XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to add a line break to the XML output with my XSLT.

here  is what I'm trying to do.

```
<Description>
        <xsl:value-of select=concat($var1,ADD_LINE_BREAK,$var2,ADD_LINE_BREAK,$var3)"/>
</Description>
```

* I realize that ADD_LINE_BREAK is not correct XSLT syntax

The xml output would then look something like this:

```
<Description>

$var1

$var2

$var3

</Description>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

It looks like that actually works, but I think I'm figuring out the REAL problem. Quick run down on what I'm doing. Pull XML data from a system -> use XSLT transform to massage the data -> putting xml output into a different system. I think my issue is that the system that I'm putting the data into doesn't understand the line breaks, so I might need a way to figure out how to include HTML line breaks, so that the system can consume.

I've tried this with no luck

```
<Description>
              <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
              <br></br>
              <xsl:value-of select="$var2"/>
              <br></br>
              <xsl:value-of select="$var3"/>
 </Decsription>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
<Description>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var1" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var2" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var3" />
</Description>
```

This will add a line feed (`\n`) character. Maybe you will need to add extra `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` to get the additional linebreaks in your desired output.

Comment: It looks like that actually works, but I think I'm figuring out the REAL problem. Quick run down on what I'm doing. Pull XML data from a system -> use XSLT transform to massage the data -> putting xml output into a different system. I think my issue is that the system that I'm putting the data into doesn't understand the line breaks, so I might need a way to figure out how to include HTML line breaks, so that the system can consume it.

Comment: You mean the `<br />` element?

Comment: Yes, but I can't put <br /> in my XSLT, can I?

Comment: Yes, you can. If it is well formed, in can go in the output.

Comment: What do you mean "well formed"?

Comment: By "well formed" i mean wll formed xml (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_doctypes.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Use either `&#xA;` or `&10;` for a line feed character.

Use either `&#xD;` or `&13;` for a carriage return character.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, depending on how fussy your XSLT processor or XML validation is, I've found this embarrassingly simple one works when all else -- like `&#xD;` or `&10;`, etc. -- fails (including a literal like `<br>,/br>`:

```
<xsl:text>

</xsl:text>
```

One or more lines for your preference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I had a string field called DESCRIPTION, which had line breaks between paragraphs, but the output kept showing up like this:

This was the first paragraph<br><br>This was the second paragraph.

So I used tokenize to separate everything between the <br><br> tags like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(DESCRIPTION,'&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;')">
    <item>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><br></br><br></br>
    </item>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And it worked for me.